# Proof that these polynomials form a base

Tags: polynomials

Prove that the polynomials

$$f'_n=e^{-z}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}(z^{2n}e^z), n=0,1,2,...$$

form a basis in the vector space of all polynomials. Find the expansion coefficients of the $f'_n$ in terms of the basis functions $f_n=z^n$.

I have tried for some time to prove this but I start to believe there is an error with what is being asked. I know that these really look like the Laguerre polynomials, except that the $z^{2n}$ term messes everything up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the prime in $f’_n$ represent a derivative?

Comment: @Aruralreader No, it's just notation.

Comment: $f^0'=1$ and $f_n'=z^{2n}+2n z^{2n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$. So $z$ is not in the span of the $f_n '$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Surely not? $f_2'$ also has a $12 z^2$.

Comment: I misread the definition. I only saw the   first derivative. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The degree of $f_n'$ equals $2n$. So any non trivial linear combination has even degree. This implies that for example $z$ is not a linear combination of the $f_n'$.